# Problems to add value to a nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I wrote a function that, given a dataframe, produce me a score for every column. I want to add this score to a table, structured as a nested dictionary. The problem is that when I add the score to a particular key in the nested dictionary, it will add this score to the whole dictionary with the same key. In particular this is the code:

```
kernel = input("Please enter the kernel you want to use:\n")
score = Kernel_evaluation(Estimators, x, Targets, threshold)
print (f'The score is {score}')
for dict_1 in Scoring:
    if dict_1 == dataframe.columns[x]:
        for KEY in Scoring[dict_1]:
            if KEY == kernel:
                Scoring[dict_1][KEY] = score
                break
            else:
                continue
            break

            else:
                continue
```

Scoring is the nested dictionary, containing 4 keys (I have 4 columns in the dataframe), and each of them contains a dictionary with 6 keys (I have 6 kernels to work with). When I add the value score to the correspondent key it will add me to all of the 4 dictionaries (in my example the kernel is gaussian and each of the 'gaussian' keys in the 4 dictionaries were updated with the score value each time. I do not know why it happends. Can you help me please?

The sample data is the iris dataset, and I expect a dictionary of dictionaries as this one:

```
Scoring = {'sepal_length': {'gaussian': 0.0, 'tophat': 0.0, 'epanechnikov': 0.0, 'exponential': 0.0, 'linear': 0.0, 'cosine': 0.0}, 
           'sepal_width': {'gaussian': 0.0, 'tophat': 0.0, 'epanechnikov': 0.0, 'exponential': 0.0, 'linear': 0.0, 'cosine': 0.0}, 
           'petal_length': {'gaussian': 0.0, 'tophat': 0.0, 'epanechnikov': 0.0, 'exponential': 0.0, 'linear': 0.0, 'cosine': 0.0}, 
           'petal_width': {'gaussian': 0.0, 'tophat': 0.0, 'epanechnikov': 0.0, 'exponential': 0.0, 'linear': 0.0, 'cosine': 0.0}}
```

but for each key inside the four dictionaries I want a score (that I obtained with another function, but it is a simple number). When I add this score to `Scoring[KEY][key]` it will add to all of the 4 dictionaries .

Comment: add the sample data and expected output

Comment: The sample data is the iris dataset, and I expect a dictionary of dictionaries as this one:

Scoring = {'sepal_length': {'gaussian': 0.0, 'tophat': 0.0, 'epanechnikov': 0.0, 'exponential': 0.0, 'linear': 0.0, 'cosine': 0.0},
'sepal_width': {'gaussian': 0.0, 'tophat': 0.0, 'epanechnikov': 0.0, 'exponential': 0.0, 'linear': 0.0, 'cosine': 0.0}, 
'petal_length': {'gaussian': 0.0, 'tophat': 0.0, 'epanechnikov': 0.0, 'exponential': 0.0, 'linear': 0.0, 'cosine': 0.0}, 
'petal_width': {'gaussian': 0.0, 'tophat': 0.0, 'epanechnikov': 0.0, 'exponential': 0.0, 'linear': 0.0, 'cosine': 0.0}}

Comment: but for each key inside the four dictionaries i want a score (that I obtained with another function, but it is a simple number). When I add this score to Scoring[KEY][key] it will add to all of the 4 dictionaries

Comment: can you tell me which key are you trying  to update

Comment: In that particular case I want to update all the gaussians key each with a different score, previously produced. So in the first cycle it will update the Scoring['sepal_length']['gaussian'], at the second the Scoring['sepal_width']['gaussian'] and so on. But it will update all of them at the same time with the same value

Comment: it's not updating all at same time. You are using same score for all the dictionaries

Comment: It is not the same score. I know that the code is uncomplete and it seems like this. All of this code is inserted in a for cycle like this:

`for x in range(0, len(Targets)):
    print (f'The choosen feature is {dataframe.columns[x]}')
    Estimators = []
    Estimators = Kernel_generator(x, Targets, Labels, kernel, Estimators)
    score = Kernel_evaluation(Estimators, x, Targets, threshold)
    print (f'The score is {score}')
    for dict_1 in Scoring:`


And it will continue as the code written before

Comment: `break` will only stop the inner loop, so outer loop still runs that's why all the keys are having same values. It's better you move this code to a function and then you can use `return`

Comment: Sorry, I am not so practice with indent and formattation in stackoverflow. The second break is one indent before, so the `for dict_1 in scoring` will interrupt when it found the correct key. The problem, I think, is the fact that when it see the 'Gaussian' key it will update it in all subdictionaries

Comment: I will try to move it to a function, thank you

Comment: It didn't worked. I tryed to give just one dictionary to the function, the correct one, but each times it will update all the dictionaries

Comment: can you share the code you tried

Comment: I posted the whole code (I avoid the function that produce the score) as an answer because it is too long

Comment: don't post code as answer delete it now

Comment: Ok i can update the question so

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for x in range(0, len(Targets)): 
    for dict_1 in Scoring:
        Estimators = [] Estimators = Kernel_generator(x, Targets, Labels, kernel, Estimators) 
        score = Kernel_evaluation(Estimators, x, Targets, threshold) 
        if dict_1 == dataframe.columns[x] and kernel in Scoring[dict_1]:
            Scoring[dict_1][kernel] = score
```

Comment: No it didn't work. Again it update all the 'kernel' keys in the subdictionaries

Comment: No, neither now

Comment: @AndreaCicconardi check now

Comment: I tried but again did not work. It produce me more score value that required. It is possible that the problem is related with the fact that I have more 'kernel' keys with the same name?

Comment: The problem should be related to python management of dictionaries. In practice each "subdicitonary" is not a copy, but it is a sort of link, so when it update one, every subdictionaries is updated

Comment: I solved creating the dictionary with a different way:

`Kernel = ['gaussian', 'tophat', 'epanechnikov', 'exponential', 'linear', 'cosine']
 Scoring = dict.fromkeys(targets, {})
 for key in Scoring:
     Scoring[key] = dict.fromkeys(Kernel, 0.0)`

instead of:

`Kernel = ['gaussian', 'tophat', 'epanechnikov', 'exponential', 'linear', 'cosine']
 Scoring = dict.fromkeys(targets, dict.fromkeys(Kernel, 0.0))`